# How to prevent multiple catching of exception

Tags: python, oop, exception

Is there a way to prevent multiple catching of exceptions while they ride up the stack to the top level of the program?

Here is a **very** simplified code example that illustrate the phenomenon:

```
def try_except_block(smthg):
   try:
     smthg.run()
   except Exception as e:
     print("WRONG")
     raise e

def re_call():
   f2 = Foo(True) # will throw an exception
   try_except_block(f2)

class Foo:
  def __init__(self, t):
    self.throw = t
  def run(self):
    if self.throw:
      raise KeyError
    else:
      re_call()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  f = Foo(False) # won't throw an exception
  try_except_block(f)
```

output:

```
WRONG
WRONG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 26, in <module>
    try_except_block(f)
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 9, in try_except_block
    raise e
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 6, in try_except_block
    smthg.run()
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 22, in run
    re_call()
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 13, in re_call
    try_except_block(f2)
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 9, in try_except_block
    raise e
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 6, in try_except_block
    smthg.run()
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 20, in run
    raise KeyError
KeyError
```

I would like to print only once "WRONG".

In my software, the `try_except_block` function is wrapped into an object, I have had the idea to set an attribute of this object which could flag the exception statement as "already visited" or not. I don't like this idea because of the possible side effects which could be lead by this pratice. Is there an other one?

exemple of what I had in mind (the class attribute is emulated by a global variable `flag`):

```
flag = False

def try_except_block(smthg):
   global flag
   try:
     smthg.run()
   except Exception as e:
     if not flag:
       print("WRONG")
       flag = True
     raise e

def re_call():
   f2 = Foo(True) # will throw an exception
   try_except_block(f2)

class Foo:
  def __init__(self, t):
    self.throw = t
  def run(self):
    if self.throw:
      raise KeyError
    else:
      re_call()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  f = Foo(False) # won't throw an exception
  try_except_block(f)
```

output:

```
WRONG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 28, in <module>
    try_except_block(f)
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 11, in try_except_block
    raise e
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 6, in try_except_block
    smthg.run()
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 24, in run
    re_call()
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 15, in re_call
    try_except_block(f2)
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 11, in try_except_block
    raise e
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 6, in try_except_block
    smthg.run()
  File "exception_loosing_args.py", line 22, in run
    raise KeyError
KeyError
```

Comment: If you don't re-raise the exception in your `except` - it'll stop getting propagated...

Comment: The behaviour is correct in logical terms, you *do* have two nested `try..except` blocks, both of which will catch and re-raise the exception and hence trigger the message twice. Perhaps using a less convoluted and recursive logic would be the best "fix" here...?

Comment: Thank you both.  Jon Clements: I need the exception to be catch on the top level of the program for other purposes. I have to propagate the exception: here is the dilemma.
@deceze: I can't. This code is involved in the recursive visiting of nodes of a graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand why your code does what it does, but a thing you could do that *might* suit is to mark exception objects as already-seen, rather than setting a global flag.  Like so:

```
def try_except_block(smthg):
    try:
        smthg.run()
    except Exception as e:
        if not hasattr(e, "teb_already_seen"):
            setattr(e, "teb_already_seen", True)
            print("WRONG")
        raise e
```

That way, the extra processing done by `try_except_block` will only happen once *per exception object*, which is probably what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to prevent the side effects I had in mind. Thank you